# Function without arguments is called with argument in ES6

Tags: ecmascript-6

I recently (2 days ago) started working on a front-end project, I used a boilerplate which, at some point, calls the following code:

```
export function incrementIfOdd() {
  return (dispatch: () => void, getState: () => counterStateType) => {
    const { counter } = getState();
    if (counter % 2 === 0) {
      return;
    }
    dispatch( { type: INCREMENT_COUNTER } );
  };
}
```

`dispatch` is a lambda function that receives no arguments and returns nothing. What is strange to me is the fact that `dispatch` is called later in the code with an argument which is not conforming to the definition of the method. Could someone explain to me why is that?

Comment: `dispatch` is a function in redux that dispatches an action. The action is the first parameter.

Comment: That's not ES6 code. And your typechecker failed.

Comment: @Sulthan I just verified it's a redux method but why it's not defined as `dispatch:(arg) => void` in the signature?

Comment: @Bergi could you please elaborate e little bit?

Comment: @GiorgosK. Obviously the signature is wrong.

Comment: @GiorgosK. It looks like TypeScript or Flow-annotated JavaScript. Nothing to do with ES6.

Comment: @GiorgosK. Either your types failed to check, or your checker failed to detect this